# requestFullScreen fails on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this code to go full screen:

```
function toggleFullScreen() {
  var doc = window.document;
  var docEl = doc.documentElement;

  var requestFullScreen = docEl.requestFullscreen || docEl.mozRequestFullScreen || docEl.webkitRequestFullScreen || docEl.msRequestFullscreen;
  var cancelFullScreen = doc.exitFullscreen || doc.mozCancelFullScreen || doc.webkitExitFullscreen || doc.msExitFullscreen;

  if(!doc.fullscreenElement && !doc.mozFullScreenElement && !doc.webkitFullscreenElement && !doc.msFullscreenElement) {
    requestFullScreen.call(docEl);
  }
  else {
    cancelFullScreen.call(doc);
  }
}
```

Error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'requestFullScreen.call')`

It appears on the line

```
if(!doc.fullscreenElement && !doc.mozFullScreenElement && !doc.webkitFullscreenElement && !doc.msFullscreenElement) {
        requestFullScreen.call(docEl);
      }
```

This code works on desktop devices, but when used with mobile devices, nothing happens. I wonder why. Any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The Fullscreen API ist not supported on mobile browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen

Comment: I see. How do videos do ti?

Comment: Judging from that page now there is ok support on Android, but not iPhone.